# Database issue when migrating a Trac project

Tags: database, sqlite, bitnami, migrate, trac

I am trying to migrate a series of Trac projects originally hosted on CloudForge onto a new Bitnami virtual machine (debian with Trac stack installed).

The documentation on the Trac wiki regarding [restoring from a backup](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/0.13/TracBackup#:%7E:text=Restoring%20a%20Backup&text=To%20restore%20an%20environment%20from,directory%20and%20restart%20the%20service.) is a little vague for me but suggests that I should be able to setup a new project

```
$ sudo trac-admin PROJECT_PATH initenv
```

stop the services from running

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
```

copy the snapshot from the backup into the new project path and restart the services

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

and should be good to go.

Having done this (and worked through quite a few issues on the way) I have now got to the point where the browser page shows

> Trac Error
>
> TracError: Unable to check for upgrade of trac.db.api.DatabaseManager: TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds. (OperationalError: unable to open database file)

When I setup the new project I note that I left the default (unedited) database string but I have no idea what database type was used for the original CloudForge Trac project i.e. is there an additional step to restore the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**
Just to add, the CloudForge was using Trac 0.12.5, new VM uses Trac 1.5.1. Not sure if this will be an issue?

**Edit**
More investigation and I'm now pretty sure that the CloudForge snapshot is not an SQLite (or other) database file - it looks like maybe a query type response as it starts and ends with;

> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
> ...
> COMMIT;

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anyone taking the time to read this but I think I'm sorted now.

After learning more about SQLite i discovered that the file sent by CloudForge was an sqlite DUMP of the database and was easy enough to migrate to a new database instance using the command line

```
$ sqlite3 location_of/new_database.db < dump_file.db
```

I think I also needed another prior step of removing the contents of the original new_database.db using the sqlite3 command line (just type `sqlite3` in terminal)

```
$ .open location_of/new_database.db
$ BEGIN TRANSACTION;
$ DELETE FROM each_table_in_database;
$ COMMIT;
$ .exit
```

I then had some issue with credentials on the bitnami VM so needed to retrieve these (as per [the bitnami documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/get-started/find-credentials/)) using

```
$ sudo cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

and add this USER_NAME as a TRAC_ADMIN using

```
$ trac-admin path/to/project/ permission add USER_NAME TRAC_ADMIN
```

**NOTE** that pre and post this operation be sure to stop and re-start the bitnami services using

```
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the guy from Trac Users, you need to understand that the user isnt really stored in the db. You got some tables with columns holding the username but there is no table for an user. Looking at you post i think your setup used htdigest and then your user infos are in that credential file. if you cat it you should see something like

```
username:realmname:pwhash
```

i thing this is md5 as hash but it doesnt really matter for your prob. so if you want to make a new useryou have to use

```
htdigest [ -c ] passwdfile realm username
```

then you should use trac-admin to give the permission and at that point your user should be able to login.

Cheers

MArkus

Comment: Thanks Markus, will look into this tomorrow

Comment: the -c flag in htdigest is  used to create a new file so dont use it with an existing file ore you override it.